# $\sigma$-algebra with uncountably infinite generator

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\Omega$ be uncountably infinite and $\mathcal{A}:=\sigma(\{w\}\colon w\in \Omega)$. I want to show that for
$\mathcal{A'}:=\{A\subset \Omega\colon A \text{ is countable or } A^c \text{ is countable}.\}$ it holds that $\mathcal{A}'= \mathcal{A}$.

First, I show $\mathcal{A}'\subset \mathcal{A}$.

Consider the case where $A\in\mathcal{A}'$ is countable, then we have that 
$A=\bigcup_{w\in A}\{w\}$ which is a countable union and therefore in $\mathcal{A}$.

If $A^c$ is countable we apply the same argument for the complement and since the $\sigma$-algebra is stable wrt. complements, $A\in\mathcal{A}$.

Now the other direction: $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{A}'$:

I have to show that given an uncountable $A\in\mathcal{A}$, its complement is countable. I would appreciate a little hint here.

Comment: very standard: $\mathcal{A}'$ is a sigma-algebra containing $\{\{w\} : w \in \Omega\}$, so it contains $\mathcal{A}$, by definition.

Comment: "I have to show that given an uncountable $A\in\mathcal{A}$, its complement is countable. I would appreciate a little hint here." This is not true in general and this is not what you have to show!

Comment: Next Q: Prove that $A$ is not generated by any countable subset of $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to verify that $\mathcal A'$ is a sigma algebra. This is straightforward. Then you observe that each $\{w\} $ belongs to this sigma algebra. It then follows that that smallest sigma algebra containing all the singletons $\{w\}, w \in \Omega$ is contained in $\mathcal A'$. This means $\mathcal A \subset \mathcal A'$.

Comment: I did this, thanks. Is the rest of the proof ok?

Comment: Yes, you have proved the  other inclusion correctly.